# I am not able to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Kernal Panic error

Tags: 14.04, boot, kernel, uefi, linux-headers

Hi I have one laptop HP Folio 9470m, HDD 500 GB, RAM 4 GB, Processor i5. I am trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS from my Pen Drive bootabled it with Rufus but at the time of booting screen is getting freeze in uefi mode and in mbr getting error **Kernel Panic** . 
 I have downloaded OS from Ubuntu twice and googling since 3-4 days, please help to solve the problem and install it into my laptop.

**Note -** I am able to install the os on other laptops without any issue with normal process only facing problem on this laptop.

**Current file system of my laptop HDD is GPT**

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to boot the pen drive and get to the "Try Ubuntu" option? Exactly what error message are you getting?

Comment: No, Nothing is working at the boot up page i can only see options like, Try ubuntu, Install ubuntu and last is check disk and at all option it stuck with an error of kernal panic

Comment: When first booting the pen drive, look on the very first screen for a little icon of a man and a keyboard. Either click the icon, or try touching the space bar, to bring up a menu F6 where you can select **nomodeset**, and then try clicking on the **Try Ubuntu**.